# iOS Share Camera Frame as Image

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I'm developing an image processing prototype which requires me to capture frames from the camera and process them. I'm using a third-party library which processes the frames and then they are available to me in a format defined by that library. I believe I will be able to convert it to UIImage. I need to share this captured image on Twitter / FB.

How can I achieve this? I believe I will need to convert the UIImage to some standard format like JPEG / PNG before I can upload it, correct? In that case, how do I convert UIImage to a standard format? Will I need to use any other third-party library for this purpose?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use UIImagaPickerController for camera? if yes then you have a method for taking pictures, which is

```
- (void)takePicture
```

After you call the method the following method of UIImagePickerController will be called

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

You can get the image here.

For more info http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW24

For getting data of a UIImage instance to as png or jpg you can use the funcitons

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
UIImage *image,
CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

or

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (
UIImage *image
);
```